# Why doesn't the SDL2 Renderer draw anything to my window?

Tags: c, sdl-2

I am currently working on a Chip-8 interpreter in C. For the rendering I use the SDL2 library. The problem is that I can't draw a rectangle on the screen. The SDL_RenderClear function does also not work. Maybe it is the Makefile but I have already tried to change the console flag in the linker to windows. Can anyone help me?

My code:

**main.c**

```
#include "chip.h"

#define NO_ROM_INSERTED 1

const int PIXEL_SIZE = 20;
const int CHIP_WIDTH = 64;
const int CHIP_HEIGHT = 32;

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = CHIP_WIDTH * PIXEL_SIZE;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = CHIP_HEIGHT * PIXEL_SIZE;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Event event;
    int quit = 0;

    Chip *chip = (Chip*)malloc(sizeof(Chip));
    chipInitialize(chip);

    chip->gfx[23] = 0x01;

    /*Checks if a ROM file is inserted by an argument*/
    if(argc < 2)    
    {
        printf("Error, no Rom inserted");
        return NO_ROM_INSERTED;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n%s loaded into memory\n", argv[argc-1]);
    }

    loadProgramInMemory(chip, "./Roms/TETRIS");


    if(!init(window, renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    {
        printf( "Failed to initialize!\n" );
    }
    else
    {   
        while(!quit)
        {
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0)
            {
                if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = 1;
                }
            }

            // Clear screen
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

            for(int i = 0; i < CHIP_HEIGHT; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < CHIP_WIDTH; j++)
                {
                    if(chip->gfx[i * CHIP_WIDTH + j] > 0x00) //Translates the one dimensional gfx to two dimensional screen
                    {
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
                        SDL_Rect fillRect = {CHIP_WIDTH * i, CHIP_HEIGHT * j, PIXEL_SIZE, PIXEL_SIZE};
                        SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &fillRect);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Update screen
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
    }

    close(window, renderer);

    free(chip);

    return 0;
}
```

**chip.h**

```
#include "window.h"

typedef struct chip{

unsigned char memory[4096];

unsigned short opcode;
unsigned short pc;
unsigned short stack[16];
unsigned short sp;

unsigned char gfx[64 * 32];

unsigned char V[16];
unsigned short I;

unsigned char delayTimer;
unsigned char soundTimer;

}Chip;

void chipInitialize(Chip *chip);
void loadFontInMemory(Chip *chip);
void loadProgramInMemory(Chip *chip, char *program);
```

**chip.c**

```
#include "chip.h"

void chipInitialize(Chip *chip)
{
    chip->pc            = 0x200;            // Set program counter to 0x200
    chip->opcode        = 0x0000;           // Reset current opcode
    chip->I             = 0x0000;           // Reset index register
    chip->sp            = 0x0000;           // Reset stack pointer

    chip->delayTimer    = 0x00;             // Reset delay timer
    chip->soundTimer    = 0x00;             // Reset sound timer

    for(int i = 0; i < 64 * 32; i++)        // Reset the graphics
        chip->gfx[i] = 0x00;

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)             // Reset the stack
        chip->stack[i] = 0x0000;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4069; i++)           // Reset memory
        chip->memory[i] = 0x00;

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)             // Reset registers
        chip->V[i] = 0x00;

    loadFontInMemory(chip);                 // Loads the font-set into memory
}

void loadProgramInMemory(Chip *chip, char *program)
{
    int bufferSize = 0xFFF - 0x200;         // Size of the memory which is reserved for the program
    unsigned char buffer[bufferSize];
    FILE *ptr;

    ptr = fopen(program, "rb");
    fread(buffer, bufferSize, 1, ptr);

    for(int i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
    chip->memory[i + 512] = buffer[i];  // Reads in the program and stores it in memory at location 0x200 or 512
}

void loadFontInMemory(Chip *chip)
{
    // Zero                         // Six                          // C
    chip->memory[0x000] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x01E] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x03C] = 0xF0;
    chip->memory[0x001] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x01F] = 0x80;     chip->memory[0x03D] = 0x80;
    chip->memory[0x002] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x020] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x03E] = 0x80;
    chip->memory[0x003] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x021] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x03F] = 0x80;
    chip->memory[0x004] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x022] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x040] = 0xF0;

    // One                          // Seven                        // D
    chip->memory[0x005] = 0x20;     chip->memory[0x023] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x041] = 0xE0;
    chip->memory[0x006] = 0x60;     chip->memory[0x024] = 0x10;     chip->memory[0x042] = 0x90;
    chip->memory[0x007] = 0x20;     chip->memory[0x025] = 0x20;     chip->memory[0x043] = 0x90;
    chip->memory[0x008] = 0x20;     chip->memory[0x026] = 0x40;     chip->memory[0x044] = 0x90;
    chip->memory[0x009] = 0x70;     chip->memory[0x027] = 0x40;     chip->memory[0x045] = 0xE0;

    // Two                          // Eight                        // E
    chip->memory[0x00A] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x028] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x046] = 0xF0;
    chip->memory[0x00B] = 0x10;     chip->memory[0x029] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x047] = 0x80;
    chip->memory[0x00C] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x02A] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x048] = 0xF0;
    chip->memory[0x00D] = 0x80;     chip->memory[0x02B] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x049] = 0x80;
    chip->memory[0x00E] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x02C] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x04A] = 0xF0;

    // Three                        // Nine                         // F
    chip->memory[0x00F] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x02D] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x04B] = 0xF0;
    chip->memory[0x010] = 0x10;     chip->memory[0x02E] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x04C] = 0x80;
    chip->memory[0x011] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x02F] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x04D] = 0xF0;
    chip->memory[0x012] = 0x10;     chip->memory[0x030] = 0x10;     chip->memory[0x04E] = 0x80;
    chip->memory[0x013] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x031] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x04F] = 0x80;

    // Four                         // A
    chip->memory[0x014] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x032] = 0xF0;
    chip->memory[0x015] = 0x90;     chip->memory[0x033] = 0x90;
    chip->memory[0x016] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x034] = 0xF0;
    chip->memory[0x017] = 0x10;     chip->memory[0x035] = 0x90;
    chip->memory[0x018] = 0x10;     chip->memory[0x036] = 0x90;

    // Five                         // B
    chip->memory[0x019] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x037] = 0xE0;
    chip->memory[0x01A] = 0x80;     chip->memory[0x038] = 0x90;
    chip->memory[0x01B] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x039] = 0xE0;
    chip->memory[0x01C] = 0x10;     chip->memory[0x03A] = 0x90;
    chip->memory[0x01D] = 0xF0;     chip->memory[0x03B] = 0xE0;
}
```

**window.h**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int init(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer* renderer, const 
int width, const int height);
void close(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer* renderer);
```

**window.c**

```
#include "window.h"

int init(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer *renderer, const 
int width, const int height)
{
//Initialization flag
int success = 1;

//Initialize SDL
if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
{
    printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    success = 0;
}
else
{
    //Create window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Chip-8 Emulator", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if(renderer == NULL)
        {
            printf( "Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
            success = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        }
    }
}

return success;
}

 void close(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
//Destroy window
SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
window = NULL;

SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
renderer = NULL;
//Quit SDL subsystems
SDL_Quit();
}
```

**Makefile**

```
OBJS = main.c chip.c window.c

OBJ_NAME = Emulator

all : $(OBJS)
gcc $(OBJS) -IC:\code\SDL2\i686-w64-mingw32\include -LC:\code\SDL2\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -w -Wl,-subsystem,console -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start with a recommendation - if you're at all interested in an answer, please don't make it harder to answer your question than it needs to be. Think how it looks for others - some bulk of code, with problem seemingly in not drawing anything; why this example have to have 6 files? Why does it depend on external file which we don't have and hence have literally no way to verify? Surely it is possible to shrink it down to 30 lines of single file with just init and render - literally any "hello world" for SDL2 will do. And when it works and your code doesn't - you start checking what's different.

Now to your question. You can't draw anything from your main loop because your `window` and `renderer` here are NULL - it was initialised to NULL and never set to anything else. It appears you have misconception of how function arguments works - in C, funciton arguments are passed by value, and any modification of that value is made to local funciton copy. When you pass an int, function gets copy of that int, and don't push any changes back. If you pass `SDL_Window*`, then you pass *value* of that pointer (in your case, `NULL`); when you do `SDL_CreateWindow`, you assign it to local variable and once angain can't return it back to caller, where it stays NULL. So all your render calls are passing NULL as renderer, which naturally isn't a valid renderer.

The same thing appears in your `close` - you're trying to reset passed copies to NULL, but it makes no sense, as you can't modify external value, only function-local copy.

Programming classes often teach that there is "pass by value" and "pass by reference", which I suppose is a source of that confusion. I'd rather say there is no pass-by-reference in C, you always pass value, but pointer is a value too. To be able to modify data we pass pointer to that data; to mutate int you may pass `int*`, but to mutate `SDL_Window*` you'll need to get pointer to *that* pointer - `SDL_Window**`. Take a look at how SDL itself does it: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer .

So, in short - make your `init` to be `int init(SDL_Window **window, SDL_Renderer** renderer, int width, int height);` (you don't need `const int` here either, as these are copies of width and height) instead, and modify its code accordingly. And check values of `window` and `renderer` after that call (debugger, debug printf, `if(window==NULL)` anything goes). `init` could be something like

```
int init(SDL_Window **owindow, SDL_Renderer **orenderer,
        int width, int height)
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;

    //Initialization flag
    int success = 1;

    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        success = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Chip-8 Emulator", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        if( window == NULL )
        {
            printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            success = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
            if(renderer == NULL)
            {
                printf( "Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
                success = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF);
            }
        }
    }

    *owindow = window;
    *orenderer = renderer;
    return success;
}
```

Of course call to `init` have to be modified to `init(&window, &renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)`.

While we're at it, two more things:

- Header files should have [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_#include_guards) or it will cause problems if you ever include it (directly or indirectly) multiple times.
- never, ever call your function `close`. It will (without any maybies about it) collapse on linux/UNIX systems. Think of another name that isn't reserved by widespread operating systems.

Comment: And don't use `-w` compiler flag. It suppresses all warnings, preventing compiler to hint you about possible mistakes, You want more warnings (start with `-Wall`), not less.